# Horizontal accordion plugin: working with each container individially

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, accordion

I am trying to create a jQuery plugin, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/elavado/t5fnozc2/) is the complete code. The question is: what I need to change in the plugin to work for each container as individual?

```
;(function ( $, window, document, undefined ) {

    // Create the defaults once
    var pluginName = 'accordion',
        defaults = {
            propertyName: "value"
        };

    // The actual plugin constructor
    function Plugin( element, options ) {
        this.element = element;
        this.options = $.extend( {}, defaults, options) ;
        this._defaults = defaults;
        this._name = pluginName;
        this.init();
    }

    Plugin.prototype.init = function () {

        activeItem = $("li").first(); 
        $(activeItem).addClass('active');

        $(".tab").click(function(){
            $(activeItem).animate({width: "41px"}, 500);
            $(activeItem).removeClass('active');
            $(this).parent().animate({width: "640px"}, 500);
            activeItem = $(this).parent();
            $(activeItem).addClass('active');       
        });
    };

    $.fn[pluginName] = function ( options ) {
        return this.each(function () {
            if (!$.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName)) {
                $.data(this, 'plugin_' + pluginName, 
                new Plugin( this, options ));
            }
        });
    }
})( jQuery, window, document );


$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#acor_1").accordion();
    $("#acor_2").accordion();
});
```

Comment: It's the question about plugin architecture. Architecture is your task. And I suppose that if you are writing **plugin**, you should know how to solve such problems. What I can suggest is to save current accordion element and to modify all selectors `$("li")`, `$(".tab")` and so on into `currentAccordion.find('li')`, `currentAccordion.find('.tab')` and so on.

Comment: I forgot to tell, that I am new on creating plugins, also the complete code can you check it on http://jsfiddle.net/elavado/t5fnozc2/